# swipe actions in native apps using Appium-android

Tags: android, appium

I started learning appium few days back. Well, my question is I want to swipe images in the flipkart app and zoom the image. I have tried using the below code , but the swipe action has been performed on the same page i.e.,on the same image it moved from right to left with x-axis and y-axis lines, zoom action has not been performed. Can anyone tell me please with java code on how to swipe images and zoom it.

**Below code :**

```
driver.findElement(By.className(properties.getProperty("cross_mark_className"))).click();
    System.out.println("clicked on cross mark");
    driver.findElement(By.className(properties.getProperty("home_menu_className"))).click();

    WebElement mobile = driver.scrollTo("Mobiles");
    System.out.println("scroll till Mobiles in home slider menu");
    mobile.click();
    driver.scrollTo("Top Offers!!").click();
    driver.scrollTo("Honor 4x").click();
    delay(4000);
    WebElement honor = driver.findElementById("com.flipkart.android:id/product_list_product_item_image");
    taction.tap(honor);

 driver.swipe(495,484, 52, 484, 12000);
 delay(12000);
 driver.zoom(honor);
 delay(8000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to perform swipe by using TouchAction class.

```
 TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver).longPress(x,y).moveTo(x, y).release();
 action.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try with this peace of code for dynamic swipe for all the mobile devices:**

```
Dimension dimension = driver.manage().window().getSize();
int width = dimension.getWidth();
int height = dimension.getHeight();
switch(direction)
{
case "right" : driver.swipe((int) (width*(0.20)), (int) (height*(0.50)), (int) (width*(0.80)), (int) (height*(0.50)), 6000);
break;
case "left" : driver.swipe((int) (width*(0.80)), (int) (height*(0.50)), (int) (width*(0.20)), (int) (height*(0.50)), 6000);
break;
case "up" : driver.swipe((int) (width*(0.50)), (int) (height*(0.70)), (int) (width*(0.50)), (int) (height*(0.30)), 6000);
break;
default : driver.swipe((int) (width*(0.50)), (int) (height*(0.30)), (int) (width*(0.50)), (int) (height*(0.70)), 6000);
break;
}
```